# jQuery: Fixing table rows while scrolling - performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, scroll

I have a table with different categories. Each category has a title, I wish to fix the position of that title on the top of the table when I scroll.

Simple example: If I'm seeing cars on the table, I want the `thead` to say "Cars". If I keep scrolling and start seeing motorbikes, I want it to say "Motorbikes".

Here's a snippet with a simplified version of my code to represent the example above:

```js
//start scrolling
$('tbody').scroll(function() {
  doStuff();
});

function doStuff() {

  $('.title').each(function() {

    //Set vars
    var $this = $(this);
    var childPos = $this.position();
    var parentPos = $('tbody').position();
    var currentTop = childPos.top - parentPos.top;

    //Listener
    if (currentTop <= 0) {
      $this.addClass('active')
      $('thead').find('.active').remove();
      $('.active').last().clone().appendTo($('thead'));
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('active');

    }
  });


}
```

```css
.table-wrapper {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table {
  font: arial;
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
}
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Vehicles</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="title">Cars</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Opel</td>
        <td>Corsa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Renault</td>
        <td>Clio</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Citroen</td>
        <td>AX</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="title">Motorbikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Honda</td>
        <td>Hornet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yamaha</td>
        <td>Virago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suzuki</td>
        <td>GSXR</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="title">Planes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boeing</td>
        <td>737</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boeing</td>
        <td>767</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boeing</td>
        <td>777</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also, [here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/sduknuzw/).

When doing things this way, I keep calling my entire function every time the scroll moves, so as I expected the performance is bad.

How can I optimize my code to run with scroll? All the solutions I've seen work with a `setTimeout` but I don't want to run my function only after 250ms of not scrolling, because a user might be scrolling for a while and the `thead` will not be correct.

Have in mind that I can have thousands of lines in my table. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to set a timeout for delaying the `.scroll()` call, your options are limited to optimizing your `.scroll()` event to be as fast as possible.

I've written an alternative method here, but I haven't tested it on large tables: https://jsfiddle.net/sduknuzw/69/

You'll notice I moved all the expensive computations outside of the loop and handle them on the initial load.  This allowed me to simply the `.scroll()` event and handle the expensive computations just once.

```
//initialize headers
var headers = [];
$('.title').each(function(index) {
  var header = {
    thead: $(this),
    top: $(this).parent().index() * $(this).outerHeight(),
    bottom: 0
  };
  headers.push(header);
});

//calculate header container heights
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    headers[i].bottom = (i+1 < headers.length) ? headers[i+1].top : 100000;
}
```

In the above header code, I build a header object where top/bottom are position values for an imaginary container.  This container is used later to find out what section the scroll bar is in.

I would consider this part of the code a little hacky. I don't like using CSS values for calculations because they aren't always the same across browsers. Additionally, this code doesn't accommodate rows/headers with different heights, so it probably won't work without modifying it to your needs. But it works well enough to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

To better understand the math and what I'm trying to accomplish, imagine this simplified scenario:

```
<style>
    table tr td {
        height:20px
    }
</style

<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th colspan="2" class="title">Cars</th></tr> //Row index 0
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><th colspan="2" class="title">Motorbikes</th></tr> //Row index 2
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><th colspan="2" class="title">Planes</th></tr> //Row index 5
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The 'top' value is the row index multiplied by the height of each row. The 'bottom' value is basically just the next header's 'top' value.

For our small example, the header container values would be this:

```
Car { 
    top: 0, 
    bottom: 40 
}
Motorbikes { 
    top: 40,    // Row Index * Row Height
    bottom: 100 // Next Headers Top
}
Planes {
    top: 100, 
    bottom: 140
}
```

Visually, it would look something like this:

```
-------------------  top: 0
|  th   |   Cars   |
|  td   |    1     |
-------------------  top/bottom: 40
|  th   |  Motors  |
|  td   |    2     |
|  td   |    3     |
-------------------  top/bottom: 100
|  th   |  Planes  |
|  td   |    4     |
-------------------  bottom: 140
```

The final part of the code is the `scroll` loop itself.  Because of the extra work I did above, we don't have to loop through all the `.title` objects on each scroll. This solution reduces that overhead into a couple of numerical comparisons which should be relatively cheap.

```
var headerIndex = 0;
function doStuff() {
    var scroll = $('tbody').scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= headers[headerIndex].top && scroll < headers[headerIndex].bottom) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //get new headerindex and update header
        headers[headerIndex].thead.removeClass('active');
        headerIndex = (scroll < headers[headerIndex].top) ? headerIndex-1 : headerIndex+1;
        headers[headerIndex].thead.addClass('active');

        $('thead').find('.active').remove();
        $('.active').last().clone().appendTo($('thead'));
    }
}
```

It's way more code than what you have, and there is definite room for improvement, but I would try something like this and see if you see any noticeable performance increases.

Comment: Wow, what an improvement. I'm still trying to fully understand your code, but I see that the heavy processing is out of the loop, and I understand how. Thanks a lot for that. However, in my original code, "headers[headerIndex].top" starts at 50 (height of the header) and the algorithm stops working. I'm trying to understand why the value is 50... Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain the "top" variable? I don't understand the purpose of `$(this).parent().index() * $(this).outerHeight()`.

Comment: I updated the solution to explain things a little better.  Hope it helps you understand what I'm trying to accomplish, but there are probably some improvements you could make on the math portion!